# Problems with iText on Android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I have created a PDF export with iText for my app, but there are a lot of strange problems with it. For example:

I created a headline like this:

```
PdfContentByte p = new PdfContentByte(writer);
p.setFontAndSize(f_base, 26);
p.moveText(85, 775);
p.showText("PDP Export App");
writer.getDirectContent().add(p);
```

On one of my testing devices (HTC X One, Android 4.0.3, HTC PDF Viewer) the line is displayed like it should. When I try the same on my Nexus 5 (Android 4.4.2, Acrobat Reader) NOTHING except one image is displayed. When I view the created pdf on my computer (Mac, Acrobat Reader) I see everything except the above mentioned headline.

Is this a bug, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should surround `p.setFontAndSize` ... `p.showText` with `p.beginText` and `p.endText`. That been said... you are creating a PDF; so why don't you use the higher level APIs of iText?

Comment: Thanks mkl, that solved my problem! :-) I use `PdfContentByte`, as I need just one line of text that I can place with an absolute value on my document. For the rest of my document I use a `table` with `cell`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just to make the solution in the comments to the original question an actual answer...*

You should surround text operations with `p.beginText` and `p.endText`:

```
p.beginText();                // <<<<<
p.setFontAndSize(f_base, 26);
p.moveText(85, 775);
p.showText("PDP Export App");
p.endText();                  // <<<<<
```

Text drawing related operations are only allowed in a text object. You can find an overview of which operations are allowed in which context in Figure 9 *Graphics Objects* of the [PDF specification ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

[image: Figure 9 *Graphics Objects*]